# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers'

Tags: reactjs, laravel-9

i already run npm install, but When i run

```
npm run dev
```

i got error :

> WARNING in ./resources/js/app.jsx 23:65-76 Critical dependency:
> Accessing import.meta directly is unsupported (only property access is
> supported)
>
> ERROR in ./resources/js/app.jsx 15:0-75 Module not found: Error: Can't
> resolve 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers' in
> '/Users/blow/Sites/localhost/firstApps/resources/js'

How to solved that? I used laravel 9 + react js in one bundle

Comment: Did you run npm install?

Comment: Getting the same issue, tried installing the laravel-vite-plugin package but got peer dependency problems.  I'd suggest filing a bug report against laravel breeze but I can't figure out how to do that...

Answer (score 11):

As a workaround, you can install laravel-vite-plugin yourself but make sure you get version 0.4.0 as the latest version will conflict with the vite version used by breeze to scaffold the project (at least, this is true for vue - didn't test with react).

For copy-paste convenience:

```bash
npm install --save-dev laravel-vite-plugin@0.4.0
```

Comment: I will update this answer if/when the breeze scaffolding gets fixed and/or vite updated to 3 so that the latest laravel-vite-plugin can be used

Answer (score 4):

Same problem for me. You actually need to install 2 packages using npm. I solved it using following commands

```
npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin
npm install --save-dev @vitejs/plugin-vue
```

Answer (score 2):

//delete mix

```
rm webpack.mix.js
```

//configure package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build",
  "serve": "vite preview"
}
```

add `"laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",` in the devDependencies

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this thread while debuging migration from webpack to vite - make sure you have `"type": "module"` in your package.json file.